# Can I use sysprep to fix a booting BSOD when migrating a Windows 7 VHD to another computer?

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, sysprep

I have Windows 7 installed on a VHD file(win7eng.vhd) on my computer A. Also, I have computer B that have a copy of Win7 installed physically.

Recently, I tried to copy win7eng.vhd to my computer B and add a boot menu using bcdedit. On B's Win7, I execute:

```
bcdedit /copy {default} /d "win7eng on vhd"
bcdedit /set {some-guid} device vhd=[D:]\win7eng.vhd
bcdedit /set {some-guid} osdevice vhd=[D:]\win7eng.vhd
```

Then, on B, when I try to boot into "win7eng on vhd", several seconds after the Windows logo animation, I see blue screen of death. The screen shot is:

[image]

B is a normal PC with no special disk controller(actually a VMware Workstation VM running on VMware Workstation 8.0), that is, Win7's install DVD has stock driver for its all hardware.

**My question:** How can I fix it on computer B? I know something about the sysprep tool. If I do a `sysprep /generalize` on A then copy the generalized vhd to B, it may boot(not verified yet). If it can boot, can I do the `sysprep /generalize` thing directly on computer B(without referring to A, assume that A is stolen)?

Answer (score 0):

Although the root cause of this 0x7B BSOD is still in mystery, I manage to fix it using Paragon Advanced Recovery CD(buy Paragon Hard Disk Manager 12 Professional, listed price $99.95).

When booting into CD(an WinPE env), attach my vhd, then **P2P Adjust OS...** , select the OS on my vhd, let it fix. Works like a charm.

BTW: It is strange that the Paragon software installed inside Windows 7 lacks the **P2P Adjust OS...** menu item ( [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ETH.png) ). So I luckily find it in recovery CD.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]